# find a matching object inside array of objects

Tags: reactjs, ramda.js, nested-object

I have an array of options and an inputValue (below):

```
options : [{value: 1, name: test}, {value: 2, name: test 1}]

inputValue: {value: "1", name: test}
```

Using Ramda, I need to find if inputValue is present in the options array and return the value.

I tried:

`find(propEq("value", inputValue))(options)`, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
const R = require('ramda');

const options = [{value: 1, name: 'test'}, {value: 2, name: 'test 1'}]
const inputValue =  {value: 1, name: 'test'}

const option = R.find(R.propEq('name',inputValue['name']))(options)
```

Working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/gists/tree/main/javascript/stack_overflow_74779149).

Answer (score 0):

There are two similarly-named functions, [`propEq`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#propEq) and [`eqProps`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#eqProps).  It looks like you picked the wrong one.

`propEq` takes a property name, a value, and an object and reports whether the value for that property name in the object is (deep) equal to the value.  As Michael Easter showed, we *can* use this.

But `eqProps` takes a property name and two objects and reports whether they have the save value (again using Ramda's deep equality) at that property.

So we can write this as

```js
find(eqProps('value', inputValue)) (options) //=> {value: 1, name: 'test'}
```

This can be written point-free, so long as you don't mind calling in a curried fashion:

```js
const findInput = compose (find, eqProps('value'))

find (inputValue) (options) //=> {value: 1, name: 'test'}
```

This assumes, as per your sample, that you want to test only the single property `value`.  If you simply have an object that would be an exact match, and you just want to test if it's present, then `includes` will just work:

```js
includes (inputValue, options) //=> true
```

You can see it all in action by expanding the following snippet:

```js
const {find, eqProps, compose, includes} = R

const options = [{value: 1, name: 'test'}, {value: 2, name: 'test 1'}]
const inputValue = {value: 1, name: 'test'}

console .log (find (eqProps ('value', inputValue)) (options))

const findInput = compose (find, eqProps ('value')) 
console .log (findInput (inputValue) (options))

console .log (includes (inputValue, options))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to find a match if the value in inputValue is a string, and options has value as a number:
options : [{value: 1, name: test}, {value: 2, name: test 1}]

inputValue: {value: "1", name: test}

Comment: Yes.  Have you tried it yourself?  Perhaps you should raise this as a separate question.